# what is the `i` type selector in SASS targetting a component of react-router-dom (NavLink) in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

edit: i figured it out, there is no `<i>` element being used such that `i` selector can have any meaning in the code. he should have applied the `transition` property to the `<svg>` selector. i also understood the use of pseudo-elements (:

i am a beginner to React JS and was following a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/ESHaail1eGc). he was creating a sidebar using `NavLink` and `fortawesome icons`, and for [styling](https://youtu.be/ESHaail1eGc?t=897) it he used `i` type selector. as far i know, isn't  tags used for italics? is that used it `NavLink`? If not, what is it styling?

Additionally is the `svg` selector targeting the imported icons could you help me understand what the `:after` pseudo-elements are doing? i am finding it hard to understand.

here is the sidebar component

```
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import './index.scss'
import LogoS from '../../assets/images/logo-s.png'
import LogoSubtitle from '../../assets/images/logo_sub.png'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faEnvelope, faHome, faUser } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

const Sidebar = () => {
  return (
    <div className="nav-bar">
      <Link className="logo" to="/">
        <img src={LogoS} alt="logo" />
        <img className="sub-logo" src={LogoSubtitle} alt="Sandesh" />
      </Link>

      <nav>
        <NavLink exact="true" activeclassname="active" to="/">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} color="#4d4d4e" />
        </NavLink>

        <NavLink
          exact="true"
          activeclass
          name="active"
          className="about-link"
          to="/about"
        >
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser} color="#4d4d4e" />
        </NavLink>

        <NavLink
          exact="true"
          activeclassname="active"
          className="contact-link"
          to="/contact"
        >
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEnvelope} color="#4d4d4e" />
        </NavLink>
      </nav>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Sidebar
```

and here is its sass file code

```
.nav-bar {
  background: #181818;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  min-height: 500px;

  .logo {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 0;

    img {
      display: block;
      margin: 8px auto;
      width: 24px;
      height: auto;

      &.sub-logo {
        width: 50px;
      }
    }
  }

  nav {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    height: 210px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -120px;
    width: 100%;

    a {
      font-size: 22px;
      color: #4d4d4e;
      display: block;
      line-height: 51px;
      height: 51px;
      position: relative;
      text-decoration: none;

      i {
        transition: all 0.1 s ease-out;
      }

      &:hover {
        color: #ffd700;

        svg {
          opacity: 0;
        }

        &:after {
          opacity: 1;
        }
      }
   }
}
```

(styling for the sidebar component is obviously incomplete)

here is the repository of the completed portfolio website: https://github.com/bobangajicsm/react-portfolio-website/tree/master

`preettier` config used:

```
{
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "tabwidth": 2,
    "semi": false,
    "singleQuote": true
}
```

i searched for an explanation but i could not find any satisfactory answer.

Comment: I've copy/pasted your code and see no `i` element nested in any anchor tag, nor do I see that in the source code you reference. The author of that repo is also using `react-router-dom@6` but still using v5 `NavLink` props. My guess is that they don't really know what they are doing and have included code they copied from elsewhere and don't understand.

Comment: @DrewReese you are right that there is no `i` element nested in any anchor tag. he should have set the transition property  in
```svg {
          opacity: 0;
        }```

Answer (score 0):

I think the **i** here targets the **< i>** element here, which is used to represent the icon in the Navbar. The transition property is used to specify a smooth transition for any changes in properties applied to the  elements.

I hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).